# Boolean algebra: How to prove this normal form equation?

Tags: logical-operators, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-algebra

I am learning boolean algebra. But I have no idea how to prove this equation ?

The book said:

> "We can transform any logic expression into normal form by factoring it about each input variable using the identity"

[image]

Comment: This is math, not programming.

Comment: So I said it's  boolean algebra...

Comment: There's a [more appropriate](https://math.stackexchange.com/) forum for this type of question - Stack Overflow is for programming-related questions.

Comment: You can prove this identity case-by-case. The input variable `Xi` can either be `true` or `false`. In both cases, the identity holds. Performing this `Shannon Expansion` recursively does yield a `sum-of-products` disjunctive normal form (`DNF`).

Comment: @AxelKemper Thank you very much. You are very professional！